# Corona showOverlay wont appear a second time

Tags: lua, composer-php, overlay, coronasdk

I've a problem with my showOverlay function. In my scene2 I have a button click that shows 'composer.showOverlay()', it does show the overlay, but when I try to open it for a second time, after closing it with 'hideOverlay()', it does nothing. I first have to go back to scene1 and then to scene2 for it to show the overlay again. I've no idea where my code is wrong, I googled, and all codes were similair to mine.

Here the code:

scene2.lua, button for the showOverlay()

```
local function reminderBtn( event )
-- OVERLAY SCENE
local sceneOverlayOptions = 
{

    time = 100,
    effect = "slideLeft",
    -- PASS PARAM VAR TO NEXT SCENE
    params = { result = "Overlay Example" },
    isModal = true
}
-- SHOW OVERLAY SCENE AFTER PRESS ON reminderBtn
composer.showOverlay( "sceneOverlay", sceneOverlayOptions)
return true
end

local tabButtons = 
{
    {
        id = "tab1",
        width = 32, 
        height = 32,
        defaultFile = "images/Alarm_Clock-32.png",
        overFile = "images/Alarm_Clock-32.png",
        labelYOffset = -1,
        onPress = reminderBtn,
    },
    {
        id = "tab2",
        width = 32, 
        height = 32,
        defaultFile = "images/Checked-32.png",
        overFile = "images/Checked-32.png",  
        labelYOffset = -1,          
        onPress = homeBtn,
    },
    {
        id = "tab3",
        width = 32, 
        height = 32,
        defaultFile = "images/Image_File-32.png",
        overFile = "images/Image_File-32.png", 
        labelYOffset = -1,           
        onPress = test,
    }
}

local tabBar = widget.newTabBar
{
    top = display.contentHeight - 40,
    width = display.contentWidth,
    buttons = tabButtons,
}

sceneGroup:insert( tabBar )
```

sceneOverlay.lua

```
-- FUNCTION FOR WHENEVER hideOverlayBtn IS PRESSED
local function goBack( event )
if (event.phase == "ended") then    
    composer.hideOverlay( "slideRight", 250)
    return true
end
end

-- "scene:create()"
function scene:create( event )
local sceneGroup = self.view

-- GET PARAM VAR FOM SCENE 2
local params = event.params.result

--CREATE A RECTANGLE (SCREEN OVERLAY)
local overlayRectangle = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
overlayRectangle.x = display.contentWidth / 2
overlayRectangle.y = display.contentHeight / 2
overlayRectangle:setFillColor( 0.8, 0.80, 0.8)

local hideOverlayBtn = widget.newButton
{
    left = 100,
    top = 200,
    id = "button1",
    label = "Back",
    onEvent = goBack
}
hideOverlayBtn.x = display.contentWidth / 2
hideOverlayBtn.y = display.contentHeight / 2

sceneGroup:insert( overlayRectangle )
sceneGroup:insert( hideOverlayBtn )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think thats because the tabButton is already *selected*.. You cant tab the tabButton twice in a row.. Try using a button for the sceneOverlay .. and keep the tabButtons to move between scenes ..

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro! I got it working now. It was indeed selected so it did not work. I set the tabBar on 'not selected', and after presseing the 'back' on the overlay, I set it to 'not selected' again.